# Is it possible to to cache collections in session cache?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I have read that collections within entities can be explicitly cached within second-level cache by `@Cache` annotation or its xml equivalent in hibernate. Now if i have a big txn within which a `@ManyToMany` kind of collection is going to be accessed multiple times, is it possible to indicate to hibernate to cache the join query results in its first-level cache so that every time after the first time that collection is accessed , hibernate looks up in its session cache rather than firing a query ? 
Does having FlushMode AUTO affect the efficacy of first-level cache access ?

Answer (score 0):

If the `@ManyToMany` collection is accessed once, the results will be kept in the first level cache for the duration of the session.

If it's not practical to keep around the same hibernate session for executing the multiple tasks, then `@Cache` and the second level cache is more convenient.

`FlushMode.AUTO` means that Hibernate will decide when the session should be flushed, meaning queries are generated and sent to the database (but no commit is made yet).

This effectively synchronizes the database with the objects in memory, so that further queries will already see the modifications done via the session so far. This functionality does not have any direct influence on the efficacy of accessing the first level cache.